# GEE Radiation dataset with unit MJ/m^2

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm using the APSIM crop model to simulate maize yield. The input features include the "Radiation", whose unit is MJ/m^2.

I want to use some radiation datasets as input to the crop model, and I find the MCD18A1.061 Surface Radiation Daily/3-Hour dataset [link](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/MODIS_061_MCD18A1#bands).

But the unit of this dataset is W/m^2, could you tell me how to transfer it to MJ/m^2, or where can I find a radiation dataset with MJ/m^2 unit on GEE?

I try to use this equation to convert the value:
[image]

But the transferred value range is a little weird. For example, the radiation value used in crop models is generally around 10, and after converting it to W/m^2 using this formula, it becomes 2777 W/m^2. However, this value is obviously much higher than the max value in the GEE dataset, which is 1400.